# IE 7 Navigation to the page was cancelled

Tags: internet-explorer

This is going to sound weird but on one of my client's sites, a specific page alone refuses to load in IE. It says waiting for website and then jumps to the error page. The same page works as it should in FF, Chrome and Opera.

Is this a JS error or something on the server side? Hope I am making sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Newbie: Without seeing the page, it is impossible to say what is causing the problem. It could be something loading in the page or the server could be resetting the web browser's connection for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Put IE8 in compatibility mode and use its debugger to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, it could be a document being cut off early or something causing an infinite 301/302 redirect loop.